# Object kept falling as opposed to shooting trajectory (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

everyone! I am new to Unity and try to create a 2D arcade game by allowing my character to jump up at a trajectory motion to reach something then fall down. I use *gravity scale* equal to 1 and *move_speed* 1000 and *rest_speed* 500 but as soon as I hit space, the character just fell down instead of going up.

Also, walk.IsWalk is an int from Walking class(as soon as I hit right arrow, set IsWalk to 2 for example). My expected result would be as soon as we hold both **space** and **right arrow** key, the character should move upwards follow a curved motion. I dont know what is going on here, can anyone kindly point me to a direction? Thanks!

My code as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Jumping : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb2D;
    Animator anim;
    Walking walk = new Walking();
    public float move_speed;
    public float rest_speed;

    void Start()
    {
        rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //float xmove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        //float ymove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        //var curr = new Vector2(xmove, ymove);

        if (Input.GetKey("space"))
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("JumpButtonPres");
            rb2D.gravityScale = 1;

            if (walk.isWalk == 2) 
            {
                rb2D.AddForce(rb2D.position * move_speed);
            }
            else if (walk.isWalk == 1) 
            {
                //rb2D.velocity += (Vector2.up * (-rb2D.velocity.x));
                rb2D.AddForce(-rb2D.position * move_speed);
            }
            else
            {                
                rb2D.AddForce(rb2D.position * rest_speed);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

partial code for rigidbody2D.AddForce

Comment: "walk.IsWalk is a bool from Walking class". This is not true. You cannot compare bool with int. Your code should not compile if that statement is true. By the way, edit your question and put your actual code in it instead of a picture of your code.

Comment: Sorry I said that wrong, I set walk.IsWalk as Int and compared it here with int

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is that whenever you are adding force to your rigidbody, you are multiplying it by the position where it's located, so by this i'm guessing your character is placed at a negative y component coordenate, and this is why **rb2D.position * rest_speed** will result on your playing falling. Change it for **vector2.up * rest_speed** and you should be fine.

Hope I was able to help.

- Noé